# How to find an intersection point between a circle and list of data points

Tags: list-manipulation

I make a circle with radius as below

```
Ctest = Table[{0.05*Cos[Theta*Degree], 0.05*Sin[Theta*Degree]}, {Theta, 1, 360}] // N;
```

And herewith is my list of data points

```
pts = {{0., 0.}, {0.00493604, -0.00994539}, {0.00987001, -0.0198918}, {0.0148019, -0.0298392}, {0.0197318, -0.0397877}, {0.0246596, -0.0497372}, {0.0295853, -0.0596877}, {0.0345089, -0.0696392}, {0.0394305, -0.0795918}, {0.04435, -0.0895453}, {0.0492675, -0.0994999}, {0.0541829, -0.109456}, {0.0590962, -0.119412}, {0.0640075, -0.12937}, {0.0689166, -0.139328}, {0.0738238, -0.149288}, {0.0787288, -0.159249}, {0.0836318, -0.169211}, {0.0885327, -0.179173}, {0.0934316, -0.189137}, {0.0983284, -0.199102}, {0.103223, -0.209068}, {0.108116, -0.219034}, {0.113006, -0.229002}, {0.117895, -0.238971}, {0.122781, -0.248941}, {0.127666, -0.258912}};
```

I would like to know the intersection between a circle and list data point as shown by figure below. How to make its program automatically? I mean that if one day I would like to change the radius of circle, the program would still work.

[image]

Comment: Unclear what is wanted here. Suppose none of the data points are on the circle? What is intended by "intersection"?

Comment: `Intersection[cTest, l]` is what I get from your question, but I assume you mean something else?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, I want to know the intersection point between a circle and a curve. I used Mathematica v10.3

Comment: What I see from your code is a list of points that lie on a circle, and another list of point. Could you specify _exactly_ what you would like? To find the point of intersection of two interpolating curves?

Comment: @anderstood, 
I want to know the point of intersection between the points of the circle with the points of the curve.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)" *)

Ctest = Table[{0.05*Cos[Theta*Degree], 
     0.05*Sin[Theta*Degree]}, {Theta, 1, 360}] // N;

pts = {{0., 
    0.}, {0.00493604, -0.00994539}, {0.00987001, -0.0198918}, \
{0.0148019, -0.0298392}, {0.0197318, -0.0397877}, {0.0246596, \
-0.0497372}, {0.0295853, -0.0596877}, {0.0345089, -0.0696392}, \
{0.0394305, -0.0795918}, {0.04435, -0.0895453}, {0.0492675, \
-0.0994999}, {0.0541829, -0.109456}, {0.0590962, -0.119412}, \
{0.0640075, -0.12937}, {0.0689166, -0.139328}, {0.0738238, \
-0.149288}, {0.0787288, -0.159249}, {0.0836318, -0.169211}, \
{0.0885327, -0.179173}, {0.0934316, -0.189137}, {0.0983284, \
-0.199102}, {0.103223, -0.209068}, {0.108116, -0.219034}, {0.113006, \
-0.229002}, {0.117895, -0.238971}, {0.122781, -0.248941}, {0.127666, \
-0.258912}};

reg = RegionIntersection[Line[Ctest], Line[pts]]

(* Point[{{0.0222112, -0.0447938}}] *)
```

**START EDIT:** As requested in comment

```
coord = reg[[1, 1]]

(* {0.0222112, -0.0447938} *)
```

**END EDIT**

```
Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[Ctest], Gray, Line[pts], Red, 
  AbsolutePointSize[5], reg}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I get it. Anyway, How to take the number only (delete word "Point")

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, which does not interpolate and search for the intersection, but instead finds the next nearest points of the circle data and the data from the list `pts`:

```
Ctest = Table[{0.05*Cos[Theta*Degree], 
    0.05*Sin[Theta*Degree]}, {Theta, 1, 360}];

pts = {{0., 
    0.}, {0.00493604, -0.00994539}, {0.00987001, -0.0198918}, \
{0.0148019, -0.0298392}, {0.0197318, -0.0397877}, {0.0246596, \
-0.0497372}, {0.0295853, -0.0596877}, {0.0345089, -0.0696392}, \
{0.0394305, -0.0795918}, {0.04435, -0.0895453}, {0.0492675, -0.0994999}, 
{0.0541829, -0.109456}, {0.0590962, -0.119412}, {0.0640075, -0.12937}, 
{0.0689166, -0.139328}, {0.0738238, -0.149288}, {0.0787288, -0.159249}, 
{0.0836318, -0.169211}, {0.0885327, -0.179173}, {0.0934316, -0.189137}, 
{0.0983284, -0.199102}, {0.103223, -0.209068}, {0.108116, -0.219034}, 
{0.113006, -0.229002}, {0.117895, -0.238971}, {0.122781, -0.248941}, 
{0.127666, -0.258912}};

nearestFromCircle = Flatten[Nearest[
    Ctest -> {"Element", "Distance"}, pts, {1, Infinity}], 1];

circlePoint = 
  Select[nearestFromCircle, #[[2]] == 
     Min[nearestFromCircle[[All, 2]]] &];

nearestFromPts = Flatten[Nearest[
    pts -> {"Element", "Distance"}, Ctest, {1, Infinity}], 1];

ptsPoint = 
  Select[nearestFromPts, #[[2]] == Min[nearestFromPts[[All, 2]]] &];

alldata = Partition[Flatten[{Ctest, pts}], 2];

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[alldata[[All, 1]]];
{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[alldata[[All, 2]]];

g1 = ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Blue];
g2 = ListPlot[Ctest, PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[g1, g2, 
 Epilog -> {{PointSize[Large], Blue, 
    Point[ptsPoint[[1, 1]]]}, {{PointSize[Large], Red, 
     Point[circlePoint[[1, 1]]]}}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]
```

[image]

The two nearest points are:

```
circlePoint[[1, 1]]
{0.021918557339453873`, -0.044939702314958356`}
```

and

```
ptsPoint[[1, 1]]
{0.0246596`, -0.0497372`}
```